# how do i execute a php script on my github site?

Tags: php, apache, github, jekyll, gallery

i want to make an image gallery for my website that pulls jpg files from a directory, so i don't have to individually write `<img>` tags for all 100+ images. a [php gallery](https://github.com/QuantaThemes/Image-Gallery-From-Folder-PHP/tree/master/images) seems to be the only way to go (though i'm open to other suggestions that might involve pure jquery/ajax, if that's possible!)

i have a very preliminary understanding of php. i've installed php 7 and apache 2.4, they're currently in the root directory of my computer. i was able to create a very basic 'hello world' index.html with a [generated php image](https://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml), which is also saved in the root directory at `C:/Apache24/htdocs` and hosted at `http://localhost`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
 echo "<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>\n";
?>
<img src="myimage.php" alt="Image created by a PHP script" width="200" 
height="80">
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

however, all of my website files are located in `C:/Documents/Github/xxxx/xxxx`, which is where i usually push all of my commits from. i use jekyll as a server to test my site offline but there's no liquid code involved (it's a one pager written all in HTML and is hosted at `http://localhost:4000`)

this is how it looks when i copy the code from the 'hello world' index.html to my website index.html:

[image]

so i am wondering how to execute php on my website, which is hosted on github. i have a basic understanding of how it works locally at my root directory, but i'm not sure how to execute it in my local/remote github repos.

do i need to move the php folder? edit the .ini or httpd.conf files? install a plugin?

thanks!

**EDIT:** so i was able to get the php script to execute locally, but when i pushed my changes to github, the script wasn't executed?

**LOCAL WEBSITE**

[image]

**REMOTE WEBSITE**

[image]

Comment: To my understanding, Github Pages are static sites. This cannot be done.

Comment: @plttn technically i'm only using jekyll as a server to test my website. my site is a one pager with only one index.html home page. i don't use github pages or any jekyll templates or liquid code, so i could easily delete the jekyll files if that would make things easier.

Comment: Where physically is the site running off of? Is it running off of localhost, or is it running on an accessible URL thanks to Github?

Comment: @plttn the website is live (thepeoplesday.org) and running off of an accessible url thanks to github, which is where i host all of my files. all of my commits are pushed from a local repository saved on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

okay, i may have figured this out.

i deleted the individual php and apache folders, and instead used wamp as my server instead of jekyll.

i then relocated my github repository to the `wamp/www` directory, and the php script is now executable on the local index.html file. i think a php interpreter is what might have been missing.

i am still having issues with getting the script to work on the live website.